# SteamKit2 - Not getting any callbacks?

Tags: c#, steam

I am trying to create a simple steam bot with SteamKit2 and C#, but am running into issues connecting. This code will ask me for all credentials, but never do anything else after that (wont even reach the end of the program, think its stuck in the while loop)

Code (http://hastebin.com/idikidixaq.cs):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SteamKit2;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace chatbot
{
    class Program
    {
        static string user, pass;
        static SteamClient steamClient;
        static CallbackManager manager;
        static SteamUser steamUser;
        static bool running = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Chat Bot\n\n";
            Console.Write("Enter Username: ");
            user = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter Password: ");
            pass = Console.ReadLine();

            SteamLogIn(user, pass);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void SteamLogIn(string u, string p)
        {
            steamClient = new SteamClient();
            manager = new CallbackManager(steamClient);
            steamUser = steamClient.GetHandler<SteamUser>();

            new Callback<SteamClient.ConnectedCallback>(onConnected, manager);
            new Callback<SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback>(onLogOn, manager);

            steamClient.Connect();
            while (running)
            {
                manager.RunWaitCallbacks(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            }
        }

        static void onConnected(SteamClient.ConnectedCallback callback)
        {
            if(callback.Result != EResult.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! {0}", callback.Result);
                running = false;
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Steam.\nLogging In...\n");
            steamUser.LogOn(new SteamUser.LogOnDetails
            {
                Username = user,
                Password = pass,
            });


        }

        static void onLogOn(SteamUser.LoggedOnCallback callback)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(callback);
        }
    }
}
```